# How to get the compiled circuits and measurements from a Qiskit Runtime job

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, qiskit-runtime

I have not been able to find any way to retrieve the compiled circuits and the measurement counts used for a Qiskit Runtime job. [This](https://qiskit.org/documentation/partners/qiskit_ibm_runtime/how_to/error-suppression.html) page describes the various error suppression mechanisms available. The thing that I am wondering is how to go query the exact jobs that were run executed in Runtime. For example, in the case of ZNE it would helpful to know what the measurements were for the different circuit folding scale factors in order to try different extrapolations. In the case of dynamical decoupling, it would be nice to be able to see the exact compiled circuits that were executed.

From what I can tell, there is no object in the Runtime jobs which contains the measurements and compiled circuit information. The most information I have been able to find is the *original* circuit submitted to Runtime, along with the expectation value (in the case of the Estimator program) and variance associated with each sub-job that was run.

Has anyone been able to retrieve this information from a runtime job?